# Beta decay in astronomy

Tags: astrophysics

In what astronomical scenario beta decay happen? I suppose that this process can happen in many astrophysical events, but where is more probable? or is it unlikely to manifest?

Comment: This looks like an assignment you have been given. Is it? What is the background or context to you asking this question?

Comment: Hint: how are neutrons created?

Comment: @PM2Ring Inverse beta decay ?

Comment: @ProfRob I assume the OP is interested in all forms of astrophysical beta decay, but surely the positron emission in the p-p chain is the most prominent. FWIW, I'd just call that beta+ decay. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay inverse beta decays involves a neutron or proton being hit by a lepton. That seems like a sensible convention to me, but I'm not a real particle physicist. ;)

Comment: Most of the neutrons in the universe were created by inverse beta decay $ p + e \rightarrow n +\nu $, with either free protons or in nuclei.

Comment: Were they, or were they formed directly out of "free" quarks?  Wikipedia suggests that barogenesis produces a n:p ratio of about 1:1, and then neutrons react with positrons and neutrinos to produce protons resulting in a n:p ratio of 1:6.  While some neutrons would be formed from protons by the inverse process, most neutrons are primordal. They were formed directly from quarks as the temperature dropped below 10^12 K.  I am well out of my depth here.  Not waving but drowning.

Comment: I was only talking about the neutrons being created in the modern universe. Certainly, most neutrons are in the primordial helium produced during Big Bang nucleosynthesis.

Comment: @JamesK I´m creating a game using the standard model, and the idea is to be educative, so i want to put it in context, i wanna know if it happens in star core´s when they are at principal secuence phase or i dont know in the surface of a neutron star

Comment: @JamesK that´s something to start, thanks very much.